# Selecting Data for Non-Parametric Testing in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm having troubles selecting data from a dataset in R. I would simply use c() and save this to a variable, but there is too much data to do this. The structure of the data is below:

```
sex  x outcome 
m   bc   3
m   bc   4
f   bc   5
f   bc   6
m   ac   3
m   ac   2
f   ac   2
f   ac   2
...
```

So what I need is this data to be split into 4 groups, ie. (m,bc) & (f,bc) & (m,ac) & (f,ac) based on the headers. I'm going to be using bootstrapping method to analyze this data later.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe you could post the output of `str(yourData)`

Answer (score 0):

See `?subset` for details:

```
sex <- rep(rep(c("m", "f"), each=2), 2)
x <- rep(c("bc", "ac"), each=4)
outcome <- 1:8

df <- data.frame(sex, x, outcome)

subset(df, sex=="m" & x=="bc")
#  sex  x outcome
#1   m bc       1
#2   m bc       2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`

```
split(df$outcome, paste(df$sex,df$x))
```

or the functions in `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)
dlply(df, c("sex","x"))
```